# R stacked bar charts including "other" (using ggplot2)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to make a stacked barchart that describes abundances of taxa at two locations in three different seasons. I'm using ggplot2. Making the plot is ok, but I have 48 taxa so I end up with a lot of different colours in the bar. There are only eight taxa that occur frequently and abundantly, so I'd like to group the others into "Other" for the plot.

My data looks like this:

```
SampleID     TransectID     SampleYear     Season     Location    Taxa1     Taxa2     Taxa3 .... Taxa48
BW15001              1            2015     fall        SiteA         25         0         0           0
BW15001              2            2015     fall        SiteA         32         0         0           2
BW15001              2            2015     fall        SiteA          6         0        45           0
BW15001              3            2015     fall        SiteA         78         1         2           0
```

This is what I have tried (modified from [here](http://userweb.eng.gla.ac.uk/umer.ijaz/bioinformatics/ecological.html)):

```
y <- rowSums(invert[6:54])
x<-invert[6:54]/y
x<-invert[,order(-colSums(x))]

#Extract list of top N Taxa
N<-8
taxa_list<-colnames(x)[1:N]

#remove "__Unknown__" and add it to others
taxa_list<-taxa_list[!grepl("Unknown",taxa_list)]
N<-length(taxa_list)

#Generate a new table with everything added to Others
new_x<-data.frame(x[,colnames(x) %in% taxa_list],
              Others=rowSums(x[,!colnames(x) %in% taxa_list]))
df<-NULL
for (i in 1:dim(new_x)[2]){
  tmp<-data.frame(row.names=NULL,Sample=rownames(new_x),
  Taxa=rep(colnames(new_x)[i],dim(new_x)    [1]),Value=new_x[,i],Type=grouping_info[,1])
   if(i==1){df<-tmp} else {df<-rbind(df,tmp)}
}
```

To plot the graph:

```
colours <- c("#F0A3FF", "#0075DC", "#993F00","#4C005C","#2BCE48","#FFCC99","#808080","#94FFB5","#8F7C00","#9DCC00","#C20088","#003380","#FFA405","#FFA8BB","#426600","#FF0010","#5EF1F2","#00998F","#740AFF","#990000","#FFFF00");

library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(df,aes(Sample,Value,fill=Taxa))+
   geom_bar(stat="identity")+
   facet_grid(. ~ Type, drop=TRUE,scale="free",space="free_x")
p<-p+scale_fill_manual(values=colours[1:(N+1)])
p<-p+theme_bw()+ylab("Proportions")
p<-p+ scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill="gray85"))+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"))
p<-p+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5))
p
```

The main problem that I would like help with today is pulling out the main taxa and lumping the rest as "Other". I think I can figure out how to group the graph by Season and Location using facet_grid() later...

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define the main taxa? Overall occurrence? Frequency of occurrence?

Comment: Take a look at the [`forcats`](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/08/31/forcats-0-1-0/) package. Specifically `fct_lump()`

Comment: Main taxa make up >90% of total abundance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
library(plyr)
d=data.frame(SampleID=rep('BW15001',4),
             TransectID=c(1,2,2,3),
             SampleYear=rep(2015,4),
             Taxa1=c(25,32,6,78),
             Taxa2=c(0,0,0,1),
             Taxa3=c(0,0,45,3))
#Reshape the df so that all taxa columns are melted into two
d=melt(d,id=colnames(d[,1:3]))
d$variable=as.character(d$variable)

# rename all uninteresting taxa as 'other'
`%ni%` <- Negate(`%in%`) # Here I decided to select the ones to keep, but the other way around is fine as well of course
d[d$variable %ni% c('Taxa1','Taxa2'),'variable']='Other' #here you could add a function to automatically determine which taxta you want to keep, as you already did

# aggregate all data for 'other'
d=ddply(d,colnames(d[,1:4]),summarise,value=sum(value)) 

#make your plot, this one is just a bad example
ggplot(d,aes(SampleID,value,fill=variable))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_grid(. ~ Type, drop=TRUE,scale="free",space="free_x")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you explain how I could add a function to automatically determine which taxa to keep? For example, those that occur in <90% of samples, or those that make up >90% of total abundance? (Or both.)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment. Take a look at the [`forcats`](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/08/31/forcats-0-1-0/) package. Without a full example, it's hard to say, but the following should work:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

temp <- df %>%
  gather(taxa, amount, -c(1:5))

# Reshape the data so that that there is one record per each amount
tidy_df <- temp[rep(rownames(temp), times = temp$amount), ]

tidy_df %>%
  select(-amount) %>%
  mutate(taxa = fct_lump(taxa, n = 2)) %>%       # Check out this line
  ggplot(., aes(x = SampleID, fill = taxa)) +
    geom_bar()
```

You can change `fct_lump(taxa, n = 2)` to `fct_lump(taxa, n = 8)` to group the top 8 categories. Alternatively, you can use `fct_lump(taxa, prop = 0.9)` to lump things up by proportions.

If you are simply going after the "presence" of the taxa in a sample (and not the value or amount), things are a bit simpler and can likely be handled in one pipe:

```
df %>%
  gather(taxa, amount, -c(1:5)) %>%
  mutate(amount = na_if(amount, 0)) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(taxa = fct_lump(taxa, n = 2)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = SampleID, fill = taxa)) +
   geom_bar()
```